# How do i prove whether a vector is a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

How do I prove $ \langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0 $ if $ A $ is a symmetric matrix?
Here $ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ denotes the dot product.

Comment: Your title at present doesn't reflect your problem in the text ("whether a vector is a symmetric matrix"?) Also, what have you tried so far? Finally: This is in general false, i.e. not every symmetric matrix is positive definite.

Comment: You have to modify your title : a vector will never be a symmetric matrix...

Comment: As a side note, if $A$ is symmetric *semi positive definite* then the statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\;x=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\implies \langle Ax,x\rangle =\langle -x,x\rangle=-1<0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the Sylvester's criterion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion.